# When calling my API from the same site, I cannot have CORS activated, because the Origin header will be missing

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I'm struggling with CORS. I have a web app that calls my API. In development, let's say the API is at site.com:3000/api and the site at site.com. In production, the API is at site.com/api and the site on site.com (which is considered "same-site").

So, my problem is that I cannot enforce CORS properly, because my API is on the same site as my web app, because the "Origin" request header will be non-existent in this case. Which means, my code can't verify it, and denies the request. And I cannot disregard the missing Origin in this case, because that would invalidate the whole CORS implementation.

I still want to have CORS, but also run APIs and site on the same origin/site. What am I missing?

I'm implementing a whitelist with cors in a nodejs app, with express and all that.

```
const whitelist = config.cors_origin_list.split(",");
var corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
      callback(null, true)
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
    }
  }
}
```

Then

```
app.use('/api/aroute', cors(corsOptions), aroute);
```

Edit: Why are people voting negatively on this? Have I done something wrong?

Comment: See this relevant GitHub issue: https://github.com/expressjs/cors/issues/118

Answer (score 1):

The first rule about CORS is that, in the absence of the `Origin` header, everything is allowed. CORS only deals with "cross-origin" requests, that is, requests in which the `Origin` header is set.

When implementing CORS, a server must never raise an error. Its only duty is to set (or not set) the `Access-Control-*` headers in the response, and the *browser* must decide whether to raise an error. For example, if the browser made the request without `Origin` header, it will process the response regardless of any `Access-Control-*` headers.

With the following code, a response from your production site will lack the headers, but the browser will not complain about that.

```js
if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
  callback(null, true); // set Access-Control-* headers
} else {
  callback(null, false); // don't set Access-Control-* headers
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem (as I see it with this) is that if you query the API directly from Postman or the browser, CORS is not enforced. Perhaps I'm thinking about it the wrong way, but that's one of the limitations I would like.

Are my expectations wrong? Should I consider CORS "only" as protecting scripts accessing the API from other sites?

Comment: Yes, CORS only protects scripts from other origins. Nothing more.